# I need to duplicate upload file in xupload yii extension

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-xupload

i have this xupload file extension:

```
<?php
        $this->widget( 'xupload.XUpload', array(
            'url' => Yii::app( )->createUrl( "/controller/upload"),
            'model' => $model,
            'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'somemodel-form'),
            'attribute' => 'file1',
            'multiple' => true,
            'formView' => 'application.views.somemodel.form1',
            'uploadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.upload1',
            'downloadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.download1',
            'options' => array(//Additional javascript options
                //This is the submit callback that will gather
                //the additional data  corresponding to the current file
                'submit' => "js:function (e, data) {
                    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
                    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
                    return true;
                }"
            ),
            )    
        );
        ?>
```

and i need to add another upload file feild, but when i duplicate the code like this:

```
<?php
        $this->widget( 'xupload.XUpload', array(
            'url' => Yii::app( )->createUrl( "/controller/upload"),
            'model' => $model,
            'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'somemodel-form'),
            'attribute' => 'file2',
            'multiple' => true,
            'formView' => 'application.views.somemodel.form2',
            'uploadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.upload2',
            'downloadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.download2',
            'options' => array(//Additional javascript options
                //This is the submit callback that will gather
                //the additional data  corresponding to the current file
                'submit' => "js:function (e, data) {
                    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
                    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
                    return true;
                }"
            ),
            )    
        );
        ?>
```

problem was when i upload images for both upload file it work on same upload template, i tryed to add uploadTemplate, downloadTemplate options but it didnt work, please tell me how to use uploadTemplate, downloadTemplate and how to render as renderPartial and in which file i render it, and should i change id in this line < script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl"> and < script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl"> upload.php and download.php templates files, please tell me what to do?

many thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the  'id'? If not change the id and try.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used XUpload with more than 1 widget in the same page, but try this:

For each of your form template (`application.views.somemodel.form1` and `application.views.somemodel.form2`) add a class, ie. 'fileupload':

```
//application.views.somemodel.form1
<form class="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>

//application.views.somemodel.form2
<form class="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Create different ids for each `uploadView` and `downloadView` ie.:

```
//application.views.somemodel.upload1
< script id="template-upload1" type="text/x-tmpl">
//application.views.somemodel.download1
< script id="template-download1" type="text/x-tmpl">

//application.views.somemodel.upload2
< script id="template-upload2" type="text/x-tmpl">
//application.views.somemodel.download2
< script id="template-download2" type="text/x-tmpl">
```

And configure your widgets as follows:

```
<?php
        $this->widget( 'xupload.XUpload', array(
            'url' => Yii::app( )->createUrl( "/controller/upload"),
            'model' => $model,
            'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'somemodel-form'),
            'attribute' => 'file1',
            'multiple' => true,
            'formView' => 'application.views.somemodel.form1',
            'uploadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.upload1',
            'downloadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.download1',
            'uploadTemplate' => '#template-upload1', // IMPORTANT!
            'downloadTemplate' => '#template-download1',// IMPORTANT!
            'options' => array(//Additional javascript options
                //This is the submit callback that will gather
                //the additional data  corresponding to the current file
                'submit' => "js:function (e, data) {
                    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
                    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
                    return true;
                }"
            ),
            )    
        );
        ?>

<?php
        $this->widget( 'xupload.XUpload', array(
            'url' => Yii::app( )->createUrl( "/controller/upload"),
            'model' => $model,
            'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'somemodel-form'),
            'attribute' => 'file2',
            'multiple' => true,
            'formView' => 'application.views.somemodel.form2',
            'uploadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.upload2',
            'downloadView' => 'application.views.somemodel.download2',
            'uploadTemplate' => '#template-upload2', // IMPORTANT!
            'downloadTemplate' => '#template-download2',// IMPORTANT!
            'options' => array(//Additional javascript options
                //This is the submit callback that will gather
                //the additional data  corresponding to the current file
                'submit' => "js:function (e, data) {
                    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
                    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
                    return true;
                }"
            ),
            )    
        );
        ?>
```

Comment: i got this error when i just changed id scripts:


< script id="template-upload1" type="text/x-tmpl">
< script id="template-download1" type="text/x-tmpl">

Error is:

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null in this js file tmpl.min.js

Comment: i added on options array these attributes: 
'options' => array(
'uploadTemplateId' => 'template-upload1', 
'downloadTemplateId' => 'template-download1',
'filesContainer' => '.files1',
'prependFiles' => true,
)
js error had gone but 2 widgets dont work together, each one working fine separately

Comment: Asgaroth, can you tell me if your widget dosnt support use more than 1 widget in the same page?

Comment: @user1942792 as I said from the beginning : "I have never used XUpload with more than 1 widget in the same page" So I can't really answer that.